# How do you go to the Big Moth Cave guarded by Dinogator in Scarlet Pillars?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-4

I have read in several article that you can make Dinogator busy by make him eating another FOE. But, how do you lure another foe to be eaten by Dinogator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several times launching food to nearby sheep, I found that the sheep interested on mushroom.

There's a sheep near the Dinogator who always move within 3 spaces back and forward, you can lure the sheep by launching the mushroom 2 tiles away from his path, when the sheep eat the food you give him, the Dinogator will be attracted to eat the sheep and move towards him, and that's your chance to enter the cave.

Comment: I think any sort of vegetation works. You also don't necessarily have to launch it you can just drop it as long as it's on the corner where the peninsula he's running on connects. And provided you don't run into him!

Comment: I throw it just to make the way to the cave shorter